# How to represent a navigation drop down menu as Java Object (for JPA)

Tags: mysql, object, jpa, menu, navigation

Is there any conventional way of dealing with the issue of having to present a drop down navigation menu for the web site as a Java object for JPA to be working with the DB.

I'm using MySQL DB, Hibernate with JPA for persistence.

The actual question would be what is the most convenient way of representing the menu in the DB. Or I need to avoid objects for this purpose.

'Drop down' means that the menu items may have unlimited (or at least few) sub-items (sub-menus).

I've started with a simple DB table for menu items comprising of id, menu item text, url and parent id, but I don't have ideas how to move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Menu and Submenu relation is very similar to Employee<->Manager association, where Employee reports to Manager and Manager can have many employees under him. This is bi-directional @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relationship.

See sample below:

```
@Entity
public class Menu {

    private int id;
    private String text;
    private String url;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_menu_id")
    private Menu parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<Menu> submenus;
}
```

On the ManyToOne field - parent, it's column will be named "parent_id" by default. You can override that column using @JoinColumn annotation.

For example, here's your menu items and its submenus:

- File

  - New
  - Open
  - Save
- Edit

  - Cut
  - Copy
  - Save

**Sample DB data**

```
[id:1, text:File, URL:/file.htm, parent_menu_id:null]
[id:2, text:Edit, URL:/edit.htm, parent_menu_id:null]
[id:3, text:New, URL:/new.htm, parent_menu_id:1]
[id:4, text:Open, URL:/open.htm, parent_menu_id:1]
[id:5, text:Save, URL:/save.htm, parent_menu_id:1]
[id:6, text:Cut, URL:/cut.htm, parent_menu_id:2]
[id:7, text:Copy, URL:/copy.htm, parent_menu_id:2]
[id:8, text:Paste, URL:/paste.htm, parent_menu_id:2]
```

Comment: How JPA will populate the parent and submenus? How should I refer the parent id column?

Comment: I updated my answer to show how data will be populated in DB. To specify the parent id column, you can use the @JoinColumn annotation. Given a submenu, you should be able to retrieve the parent id using submenu.getParent().getId();

Comment: It doesn't look very complicated, but the actual fact is that it's not working for me :-/ I had to add FetchType.EAGER to @OneToMany, because no session is present. Then the object gets created, but the parent and submenus are null, because I still haven't added the JOIN_COLUMN. After I add its name (which is correct) suddenly the whole 'menu' object gets null. No error logs are present.

Comment: Not very sure of the problem you're getting. Might help if you can post your whole Entity class plus the code you used for retrieving/saving the entity.

Comment: I found out what's the problem. I had invalid values in the parent id column. There should be NULL instead of 0 where the item doesn't have a parent. Now it's working great. Thank you!